# Calculate the part of the sphere that lies inside the cylinder.

Tags: integration, analysis, measure-theory, definite-integrals, geometric-measure-theory

Hey I have problems with this problem.

Let $\mathbb{R}^3$ be a sphere, described by $x^2 +y^2 +z^2 ≤ R^2$ , and a cylinder, described by $(x − R/2 )^2 + y^2 ≤ ( R/2 )^2$ .

a) Calculate the part of the sphere that lies inside the cylinder.

b) Calculate the part of the cylinder surface that lies inside the sphere.

To calculate the volume of the part of the sphere that lies inside the cylinder, we can evaluate the double integral of the sphere over the region defined by the cylinder:

$V = \iint_{(x-R/2)^2 + y^2 \leq (R/2)^2} \sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2} dxdy$

Similarly, to calculate the area of the part of the cylinder surface that lies inside the sphere, we can evaluate the surface integral of the cylinder over the region defined by the sphere:

$A = \iint_{x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \leq R^2} \sqrt{(x-R/2)^2 + y^2}  dx dy$

But from here I don't know how to proceed. Can someone help me?

In a more general way? How should I proceed when I have such integrals (volume of something under some conditions)

Comment: The most common way is to try to draw a figure and obtain integration bounds from the figure, although this must be  then formally confirmed. It is also common to transform variables to simplify a figure or an integrand.

Comment: The difficult part for me is to obtain the  integration bounds

Comment: Cylinder $(x − R/2 )^2 + y^2 ≤ ( R/2 )^2$ has  projection on $Oxy$ with same equation. Floor and ceiling comes from sphere - Can you continue from here?

Comment: Sorry I corrected my question

Comment: It helps to transform both inequalities' $xy$ coordinates to polars. The second implies $\cos\theta\ge0$, giving two regions for $\theta$, each of equal volume. The total is$$2\int_0^{\pi/2}d\theta\int_0^{R\cos\theta}r\int_{-\sqrt{R^2-r^2}}^\sqrt{R^2-r^2}dz,$$which I leave you to check is $\frac29(3\pi-4)R^3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outgoing from comment above integral will be
$$4\int\limits_{0}^{R}\int\limits_{0}^{ \sqrt{( R/2 )^2-(x − R/2 )^2} }\int\limits_{0}^{\sqrt{R^2-x^2-y^2}}$$
So, bounds you have. Can you finish?

Comment: So we need to solve $$4(\int\limits_{0}^{R}(\int\limits_{0}^{ \sqrt{( R/2 )^2-(x − R/2 )^2} }(\int\limits_{0}^{\sqrt{R^2-x^2-y^2}}z dz)dy)dx)$$ and the $4$ is because we have $z \leq +/-\sqrt{R^2-x^2-y^2}$ and $y \leq +/-\sqrt{( R/2 )^2-(x − R/2 )^2}$, right?

Comment: Yes, but without $z$ under integration, when you would like to calculate volume.

Comment: Okay but this was meant to be an exercise for an exam. without a calcualtor it becomes difficult to calculate the integral and it is very easy to get it wrong. Isn't there an easier way to solve this problem?

Comment: You know, "difficult" and "easy" are very subjective. Another way, as I wrote above, is find some suitable variables transformation, for example, spherical one, but, anyway it' needs  some work by hand to be done. Or, if you are allowed, you can use some math. packets Wolfram, mathcad etc.

Comment: Thank you for your help